# Create multiple databases using scala slick

Tags: scala, slick-3.0, slick-2.0

Is it possible to create multiple databases using a single query using slick?

```
 sqlu"""CREATE DATABASE if not exists students;CREATE DATABASE if NOT professors"""
```

I'm running the above slick query but getting MySQLSyntaxErrorException

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE DATABASE if NOT EXISTS professors' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

Ive found answer to my own question

```
val createDbs = DBIO.seq(sqlu"""CREATE DATABASE if not exists students""",
  sqlu"""CREATE DATABASE if not exists professors """)
db.run(createDbs)
```